# How to write a BigQuery query to find rows where a specific column changes in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I need to write a query for a table that records the date when a value changes in a column. The table is such that the following query yields the corresponding result.

```
  SELECT
    employeeId,
    date,
    location,
  FROM
    MY_TABLE 
 ORDER BY 
    employeeId, date, location
```

Result:

```
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
|    |   employeeId | date       | location         |
+====+==============+============+==================+
|  0 |         2467 | 2016-04-31 | COUNTRY A        |
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
|  1 |         2467 | 2016-05-31 | COUNTRY A        |
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
|  2 |         2467 | 2016-06-31 | COUNTRY A        |
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
|  3 |         2467 | 2016-07-31 | COUNTRY A        |
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
|  4 |         2467 | 2016-08-31 | COUNTRY B        |
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
|  5 |         2467 | 2017-09-31 | COUNTRY A        |
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
```

For every employeeId, if the location changes between two dates, I want the old date, old location, new date and new location. Here is the query that I wrote:

```
WITH
  cte AS (
  SELECT
    employeeId,
    date,
    location,
  FROM
    MY_TABLE),
  movements AS (
  SELECT
    a.employeeId AS EMPLOYEEID,
    b.employeeId AS EMPLOYEEID_NEW,
    a.date AS OLD_DATE,
    b.date AS NEW_DATE,
    a.location AS OLD_LOCATION,
    b.location AS NEW_LOCATION
  FROM
    cte a
  INNER JOIN
    cte b
  ON
    a.employeeId = b.employeeId
  WHERE
    b.date > a.date  
    AND DATE_DIFF(b.date, a.date, MONTH) = 1
      AND a.location <> b.location 
)
SELECT
  NEW_DATE,
  OLD_DATE, 
    COUNT(EMPLOYEEID) AS MOVED,
  OLD_LOCATION,
  NEW_LOCATION
FROM
  movements
GROUP BY
  NEW_DATE,
  OLD_DATE,
  EMPLOYEEID,
  OLD_LOCATION,
  NEW_LOCATION
ORDER BY
MOVED,
  NEW_DATE,
  OLD_LOCATION,
  NEW_LOCATION
```

I get the following results:

```
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|    | NEW_DATE   | OLD_DATE   |   MOVED | OLD_LOCATION   | NEW_LOCATION   |
+====+============+============+=========+================+================+
|  0 | 2016-07-01 | 2016-06-01 |       1 | COUNTRY A      | COUNTRY B      |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|  1 | 2016-07-01 | 2016-06-30 |       1 | COUNTRY A      | COUNTRY B      |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|  2 | 2016-07-31 | 2016-06-30 |       1 | COUNTRY A      | COUNTRY B      |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|  3 | 2016-07-31 | 2016-06-01 |       1 | COUNTRY A      | COUNTRY B      |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|  4 | 2016-08-01 | 2016-07-01 |       1 | COUNTRY C      | COUNTRY B      |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|  5 | 2016-08-01 | 2016-07-31 |       1 | COUNTRY C      | COUNTRY B      |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|  6 | 2016-08-31 | 2016-07-01 |       1 | COUNTRY C      | COUNTRY B      |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
|  7 | 2016-08-31 | 2016-07-31 |       1 | COUNTRY C      | COUNTRY B      |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------------+----------------+
```

The results do not seem to be correct. I highly doubt that the number of movements between two countries is always 1... Can you please have a look at the query and let me know where I am erring? Also, fyi, I have obfuscated the data provided here. I switched around country names and dates, basically.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to identify within your query how you selected the previous date and location. However, I was able to simplify it and achieve what you aim.

First, I have changed your dummy data a little bit in order to check some cases. Thus, I have used the following:

```
employeeId|date|location
2467|2016-04-30|COUNTRY A
2467|2016-05-31|COUNTRY A
2467|2016-06-30|COUNTRY B
2467|2016-07-31|COUNTRY A
2467|2016-08-31|COUNTRY B
2467|2017-09-30|COUNTRY A
2468|2017-09-30|COUNTRY A
2468|2017-09-30|COUNTRY A
```

Notice that the *employeeId* 2467 changes countries 4 times.

I have created the following script:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT employeeid, date, location, (LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY date ASC)) AS prev_date,
        (LAG(location) OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY date ASC)) AS prev_loc
FROM `test-proj-261014.bq_load_codelab.employee`
ORDER BY date
)
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE DATE_DIFF(date, prev_date, MONTH)>=1 
  AND prev_loc IS NOT NULL
  AND location<>prev_loc
 ORDER BY date
```

As you can see I used the [LAG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lag) function in order to select the previous date and location for each row. I would like to point that when LAG() is used in the first row, it returns null. For this reason a filter `WHEN prev_loc IS NOT NULL` is used.

The output is as below:

[image]

As you can see I have selected the ***employeeid*** to effectively check the results. Although, you can delete this field from the last select statement and retrieve only the fields that you wish.

Lastly, if you want to check how many times an employee has moved, you will need another piece of code to query the table above. When you use [COUNT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#count), you can not retrieve the old and new dates, as you stated above, because you are counting how many times each employee moved and grouping by the *employeeid*. That means you will have a number(count) per *employeeid*. Thus, in this case I have saved the above result in a temp table called ***final_output*** to query it as following:

```
SELECT employeeid, count(employeeid) as MOVED FROM final_output
 GROUP BY employeeid
```

And the output:

[image]

The employer who has the id 2467 has moved 4 times within the time frame analysed.